# Ember Nested Routes and rendering models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, handlebars.js, ember-router

I have an invoice application generator and i want to show the invoices with all his transactions in 2 different ways, at the moment i can only do it in 1 way ( Edit Link)

1. On Edit link where i can see all my invoices and transactions
   together ( it s how it works now)
2. On View link where i want to see only the specific Invoice information with his own transactions
       and not any of the other invoices and informations

I have reproduced my case [here](http://jsbin.com/yiwugi/12/edit?html,js,output)

This is the route code

```
App.Router.map(function(){ 
    this.resource('invoices', function(){
        this.resource('invoice', { path:'/:invoice_id' }, function(){
            this.route('edit'); 
        }); 
        this.route('create');
    });

});
```

The problem is that as long as i am inside the invoices resources i am sharing the invoices templates where everything is generated, but is there a way where i can see only my single invoice with his own transactions inside the invoices route? Is it achievable with the same Route Code? What's the best way to get this done?

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="invoices">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      {{#link-to "invoices.create"}} Add Invoice {{/link-to}}
    </div>
    <ul class="fatturas-listing">
      {{#each invoice in model}}
        <li>
          {{#link-to "invoice" invoice}}
            Edit {{invoice.title}}
          {{/link-to}}
        </li>
        <li>
          {{#link-to "invoice" invoice}}
            View {{invoice.title}}
          {{/link-to}}
        </li>
       {{else}}
        <li>no fatturas… :(
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your 'edit' part. The problem you have right now is the outlet defined in the invoices template, all sub routes will be rendered in here, so you cannot show an invoice without its parent (invoices) content.

I think the most common way is to remove the outlet and show all invoices in the InvoicesIndex route. Clicking an invoice will then go to a single invoice (a new page without showing the invoices list from the InvoicesIndex route).